# YouTube API - live broadcasts ordered by current viewers?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get a list of current live broadcasts in a given category from the YouTube Data API, ordered by number of viewers currently watching.

It looks like the liveStreamingDetails (which contains the concurrentViewers property) are only exposed on the individual video level. However, grabbing all the current streams, then making separate calls for each stream to get the number of viewers, then ordering that list is woefully inefficient and costly.

Feels like there must be a better way! Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a better way to do it at the moment.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, but hoping to get an official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no better way. Please file a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube to keep track.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For anyone else looking this has been filed as feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7674